# I want to pass data in between two activity using Intent but why it is not working?

Tags: android

I already tried this code in my activity ..

In my First Activity this is my code to pass data :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeacherSideQuestion2.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("score", finalScore);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

and in my Second Activity , here's the code to retrieve my data .

```
public void onClick() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    // int temp = extras.getInt("score", 0);
    // int temp = i.getExtras().getInt("score", 0);
    if (bundle != null) {
        int temp = bundle.getInt("score", 0);
        if (temp >= 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TeacherSideQuestion2.this,
                    CongratsEnglish.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(TeacherSideQuestion2.this,
                    FailedEnglish.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to click the onClick event , my application will crash .

can anyone fix this ?

Thank you for your answers .

Here's the LogCat says :

```
  12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
12-20 03:51:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(3051):     ... 11 more
12-20 03:51:40.223: E/Trace(3085): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: just use `startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: I will third "Post the logcat". But in the meantime, its likely that the other `Activities` aren't declared in the `manifest.xml`. Also, why are you using `startActivityForResult()` if you are starting different `Activities` and not returning a result?

Comment: you getting error at line 379 in LoadedApk.java:. what is at this line?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10397249/1265724)

Comment: @Cap droid how can I view the corresponding number of lines ? sorry for many questions because I'm just new to android .

Comment: by the way .
I'm using eclipse .

Comment: @codeMagic Yes . I already declared everything in manefest . and I also change it to startActivity().

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-eclipse/

Comment: @CapDroid my code will last only at line 149 .

Comment: There's no line 379 in here .

Comment: After using Google, this link maybe solves your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399789/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-application-android-app-applic

Comment: @kyo you are missing some of your logcat, I believe, make sure you have posted all of it from the crash. These lines don't reference your project but the Android framework instead

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,YourClass.class);
intent.putInt("score",finalScore);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in receiving class receive it like this in your onCreate()

```
int defValue = -999;
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("score",defValue);  // defalut value can be anything if score not get recieved
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **First Activity** this is my code to pass data :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeacherSideQuestion2.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("score", finalScore);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In **Second Activity**:

Declare int i as a global variable.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i  = getIntent().getIntExtra("", 0);
}

and on your button.setOnClick {
    if (i >= 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TeacherSideQuestion2.this,
                    CongratsEnglish.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(TeacherSideQuestion2.this,
                    FailedEnglish.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
}
```

Comment: stiLL . it gets crashing .

Comment: @kyo could you post these lines :
`at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)`
`at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)`

Comment: how can I view the corresponding number of lines ?

Comment: so that I can post it .

Comment: are you using eclipse ?

Comment: at the edge of your editor ... where you see the error icons, etc right click on the left edge. you should see an option called `Show Line Numbers`

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file and see if you have entries for all the activities. Check your min sdk and target sdk in manifest file and android properties.

Comment: in your second activity, try to instantiate Bundle object in onCreate and pass it as parameter to onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Change `startActivityForResult(intent,0);` to `startActivity(intent);` because you don't need to start it for a result just to pass a value to another activity.

I'm not sure if this would be a problem, but you may need to change `getApplicationContext()` to `YourActivityName.this`.

Last thing, you don't need to create a bundle to send a value to another activity. You can just do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, TeacherSideQuestion2.class);
intent.putExtra("score",finalscore);
startActivity(intent);
```